# Feedback on analysis of code example (secure coding)

Tags: c, loops, types, integer-overflow

I have a piece of code from an assignment I am uncertain about. I feel confident that I know the answer, but I just want to double-check with the community incase there's something I forgot. The title is basically secure coding and the question is just to explain the results.

```
int main() {
   unsigned int i = 1;
   unsigned int c = 1;
   while (i > 0) {
     i = i*2;
     c++;
   }
   printf("%d\n", c);
   return 0;
}
```

My reasoning is this:

At first glance you could imagine the code would run forever, considering it's initialized to a positive value and ever increasing. This of course is wrong because eventually the value will grow so large it will cause an integer overflow. This in turn is not entirely true either, because eventally it will force the variable 'i' to be signed by making the last bit to 1 and therefore regarded as a negative number, therefore terminating the loop. So it is not writing to unallocated memory and therefore cause integer overflow, but rather violating the data type and therefore causing the loop to terminate.

I am quite sure this is the reason, but I just want to double check. Any opinions?

Comment: Not quite - an `unsigned int` can never take on a signed value. You'll probably find it instructive to try compiling and running the code: http://codepad.org/VUjjtvbJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `unsigned int` will never compare against zero as a signed number. The only chance for the loop to end is for the variable to become exactly zero.

The latter will surely happen once since you multiply by 2 (an even number) in each iteration and this causes a zero bit to be inserted from right (least meaningful bit), so after some number of iterations all non-zero bits will be "shifted out of the number" and it will become zero.

Comment: I see, so it will cause integer overflow after all. It makes sense; at some point the value will be large it cannot fit inside the 4bytes and at some point no bits will be 1 in the first 4 bytes. I guess the loop would never terminate if you would simply increment the value 'i' rather than multiply it?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: It will terminate when the variable increments over the largest possible value. If you have 32-bit int you can even test it - it will happen in reasonable time.

Answer (score 2):

There is no overflow when dealing with unsigned values. All calculations are done modulo `(UINT_MAX + 1)`.

So, what happens is that the value by repeatedly multiplying by 2 you eventually wrap-around to zero ... and your loop stops

Suppose, for simplicity sake, that unsigned is 4 bits wide.

```
1 * 2 = 2 ==> 0b0010
2 * 2 = 4 ==> 0b0100
4 * 2 = 8 ==> 0b1000
8 * 2 = 0 ==> 0b0000
```

Answer (score 1):

unsigned values do not overflow; they are, in fact, guaranteed and defined to wrap-around.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: He wanted to know whether his theory was correct. That was the question. The answer is "no", for the reason above.

Comment: I'd have to agree with http://stackoverflow.com/users/641980/daniel-dubois on this one - "integer overflow" and "integer wrapping" are semantically the same thing, whether signed or unsigned. Oddly, the Wikipedia article says the exact opposite as you claim, saying both unsigned and signed "overflow" but only signed ints can "wraparound" (defined as the addition of two positives creating a negative). Honestly I don't see a point in drawing a distinction.

Comment: @Chadwick: I don't see how overflow and wrapping are the same thing, when signed integer values do not wrap around at all. You may, on some platforms, witness what _appears_ to be wraparound due to pure chance of how bits are laid out; this contrasts with unsigned values, which are defined and guaranteed to wrap around to zero when they reach their maximum value, not by chance but by design. They do not overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `signed integer`, the left most bit sets the **sign**, so the range of values that this type element can have are **-2147483648 to 2147483647**. To get negative value from positive value you do bit inverse to all bits and vice-versa.

In case of `unsigned integer`, the left most bit is use to store extra values. So i range of values that this type element can have are **0 to 4294967295**.

In binary form, when `i=1;` and you only do `i = i*2;` then values, that you can have as values are:

```
1 // 1 in base 10
10 // 2 in base 10
100 // 4 in base 10
1000
10000
100000
1000000
10000000
100000000
1000000000
10000000000
100000000000
1000000000000
10000000000000
100000000000000
1000000000000000
10000000000000000
100000000000000000
1000000000000000000
10000000000000000000
100000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000 // 1073741824 in base 10
10000000000000000000000000000000 // 2147483648 in base 10
```

Now, if you have a loop like: `while (i > 0) {` and `i` acts as described before, then it will be in a infinite loop, as it will never be 0. Overflows will occur, but thy will not brake program - it will still be running.

In case variable `i` is signed (default), then you would get output `c=32` as integer 10000000000000000000000000000000 evaluates to -2147483648 and that is `< 0`. In this case however you do not know the output.

As it is schoolwork, then naturally teachers have picked a problem, where you can not conclude anything from running the code provided. I assume, that this is because, thy want you to know how underlaying types are stored and what is difference between signed and unsigned types.

Just as an extra fact, Java does not have unsigned primitives or immutable number classes. Not having them can be painful, in some cases. It is diffidently a useful keyword.

Answer (score 0):

i is unsigned throughout. At some point it will overflow (or wrap around if that makes it clearer) and become exactly 0, it cannot ever be negative.

Comment: No; unsigned values do not overflow.

Comment: Unsigned values do not overflow, but they do wrap around. Signed values do overflow, causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you are right about the overflow, but an unsigned int is unsigned for a reason (there is no sign bit hence unsigned, an unsigned int starts at 0) therefore it will overflow to 0, if it was unsigned it would have overflown to a negative number (- 2**31 on a 32 bit machine for example)

Comment: No; unsigned values do not overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As i is an unsigned integer (0 - 255), i will equal 0 after 8 iterations due to binary round off.

Comment: With the caveat being that this is an 8-bit system, of course.